# Sorting lists with multiple tie breakers

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

I have data in an array like so:

```
array([[ 5,  5,  5,  6,  9,  6,  6],
       [10,  4, 10,  3,  5,  3,  3],
       [10,  3, 10,  4,  5,  3,  4],
       [ 9,  6,  8,  8, 10,  6,  9],
       [10, 10, 10,  7, 10,  4,  4],
       [10,  6, 10,  5,  9,  7,  5],
       [ 9,  7, 10,  7, 10,  8, 10],
       [ 8,  5, 10,  7, 10,  7, 10],
       [ 7, 10, 10,  9, 10,  7,  8]])
```

I want to sort it by the amount of non-10 values, and I also want to sort it in ascending order for rows, and in descending order of number of 10s:

```
arr = np.sort(arr, axis=1)
arr = arr[(arr==10).sum(axis=1).argsort()][::-1]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 4,  4,  7, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 5,  7,  7,  8, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 10],
       [ 3,  3,  4,  4,  5, 10, 10],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  4,  5, 10, 10],
       [ 6,  6,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  9]])
```

I want to implement a tie breaker system so that if the amount of 10s the same, it now orders by amount of 9s, then 8s, and so on. Expected output:

```
array([[ 4,  4,  7, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 7,  7,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 5,  7,  7,  8, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 5,  5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 10],
       [ 3,  3,  4,  4,  5, 10, 10],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  4,  5, 10, 10],
       [ 6,  6,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  9]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with [`numpy.frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html).

The basic idea is to construct an array with the same rows, each element of which is a tuple containing the number of 10s, 9s, etc. Then apply `numpy.argsort` to this array and get the result.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ 5,  5,  5,  6,  9,  6,  6],
                [10,  4, 10,  3,  5,  3,  3],
                [10,  3, 10,  4,  5,  3,  4],
                [ 9,  6,  8,  8, 10,  6,  9],
                [10, 10, 10,  7, 10,  4,  4],
                [10,  6, 10,  5,  9,  7,  5],
                [ 9,  7, 10,  7, 10,  8, 10],
                [ 8,  5, 10,  7, 10,  7, 10],
                [ 7, 10, 10,  9, 10,  7,  8]])
arr = np.sort(arr, 1)

keys = sorted(set(arr.ravel()), reverse=True)

def make_tuple(*argv):
    return tuple(argv)
ufunc = np.frompyfunc(make_tuple, len(keys), 1)

cnt_array = ufunc(*[(arr == k).sum(1) for k in keys])
result = arr[cnt_array.argsort()[::-1]]
print(result)
# [[ 4  4  7 10 10 10 10]
#  [ 7  7  8  9 10 10 10]
#  [ 7  7  8  9 10 10 10]
#  [ 5  7  7  8 10 10 10]
#  [ 5  5  6  7  9 10 10]
#  [ 3  3  4  4  5 10 10]
#  [ 3  3  3  4  5 10 10]
#  [ 6  6  8  8  9  9 10]
#  [ 5  5  5  6  6  6  9]]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, though I'll have to spend some time reading the documentation to understand *why*. I'm still wrapping my head around how it works, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that in numpy is to sort by the least important part of the tie-breaker, and progress up to the most important sort criteria.

E.g. if you want to sort by number of 10s, then tie-break by 9s, then tie-break by 8s, then you could do this:

```
arr = np.sort(arr, axis=1)
arr = arr[(arr==8).sum(axis=1).argsort(kind='stable')]
arr = arr[(arr==9).sum(axis=1).argsort(kind='stable')]
arr = arr[(arr==10).sum(axis=1).argsort(kind='stable')]
arr = arr[::-1]
```

Keep in mind that you need `kind='stable'` on each argsort. This means that if one element appears before another, and they are tied in the current sort criteria, the order will be kept. The default sort method, quicksort, is not stable.

Comment: While that is useful for sure, and is simple, (I am still learning numpy,) I think that it is only useful if you know how many tie breakers you will need.

Comment: What do you mean? It will still work if the tie break by 8s turns out to be unnecessary - it will just do redundant work. You can avoid some redundant work by only calling the tiebreaks if they're necessary, but that will defeat vectorization. I suspect it is a wash performance-wise.

Comment: I don't know if I'll need to tie break 7s, 6s, 5s, 4s, and lower. In a bigger dataset with bigger numbers, you'd need to copy paste until all possible rules are defined. However, thanks for the answer, I'm still new to numpy, and wasn't aware of the different sorting methods!